# solr setup with haystack

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am new to `solr 4.1.0` and was trying to set it up on my MacOSX machine using Tomcat7 and the instructions on the following page:

http://contextllc.com/node/76

I was able to do everything properly, and it worked! I then followed instructions on the haystack documentation to setup haystack and output a schema.xml file. I then created a new core using SolrAdmin and used that schema and keep getting:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text": Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class 'solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory'
```

Is there something i'm missing in the above? I have included all of the solr jar files and cannot find anything else that would be required?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why..but the issue went away after I switched to solr 3.6.2... Something definitely changed with the versions.